# Accessing DOM in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm using the example [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) as a starting point for accessing some DOM elements on the user's current tab. In popup.html, I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
```

And the first lines of popup.js are:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  // No tabs or host permissions needed!
    console.log("test");
  console.log('Turning ' + tab.url + ' red!');
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="red"'
  });
});
```

Manifest.json has the following permissions:

```
 {
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "",
"icons": { "16": "icon16.jpg",
    "48": "icon48.jpg",
   "128": "icon128.jpg" },
   "minimum_chrome_version": "46",
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon48.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["jquery.min.js", "getDescription.js"],
        "run_at": "document_start"   
    }],
"options_page": "options.html",
"permissions": ["<all_urls>", "tabs","storage", "activeTab"]
```

}

Nothing is appearing in console, as if function isn't firing at all.

Comment: Note, the popup is a separate page so to inspect it you need to rightclick it, then click inspect. You'll see your console messages there.

Comment: @wOxxOm Yes, that is what I'm doing.

Comment: Ah, you seem to use both background page for the icon click and the default_popup in manifest.json. It won't work. If you have default_popup, then do everything in your popup js script. Otherwise remove default_popup and do everything in the event/background page.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I've added the entire Manifest.json above. @wOxxOm

Comment: [Chrome Extension's Icon on click](//stackoverflow.com/a/31308640)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it mention [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#event-onClicked)  `onClicked` fired when a browser action icon is clicked. This event **will not fire** if the browser action has a popup.

If you want to have the popup and then to execute a script when the icon is clicked use below approach.

```
{
  "name": "My Extension",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version" : 2,
  "description": "la lala laa",
  "background" : {
       "scripts" : ["background.js"]
  },
  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon48.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["activeTab"]
}
```

Inside the background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
     chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "popup.js"});
});
```

Or it should work fine if you have below in your popup.html

```
<script src="popup.js"></script>
```

Inside your popup.js

```
window.onload = function() { 
    console.log("do whatever you want here !!!") 
}
```

Comment: With this method, how do I load popup.html when my extension icon is clicked?

Comment: Didn't the above work ? Try with `"default_popup": "popup.html"` and with a background script.

Comment: When I add the default popup, the script above doesn't fire. When I take it off, nothing appears when clicking the extension icon.

Comment: When you take it off and clicked  does the console show something ?

Comment: No, but I don't think I'm even accessing the console for the popup. (I don't have an option to "Inspect Popup")

Comment: Try `F12` to open the developer mode and click the icon. see the console when you are clicking the icon.

Comment: Nothing in the console. But the script is firing now, as background turns red when I click the Extension icon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172531/discussion-between-prime-and-sartorialist).